# Passing parameter/argument in AddressOf delegate VB

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, delegates

I have below piece of code and want to put those part in separate thread.

```
 Dim objThreadedReq = From reqThreaded In objRequestList
                             Where reqThreaded.IsThreaded = True
        Dim trThreadedRequests As Thread = New Thread(New ThreadStart(AddressOf PoolThreadedRequests))
        trThreadedRequests.Start()
```

I created one function PoolThreadedRequests (objRequestList As RequestList)

How can I pass objThreadedReq collection in my threaded function?

Comment: Take a look at [ParameterizedThreadStart Delegate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.parameterizedthreadstart(v=vs.100).aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Tim,

"Take a look at ParameterizedThreadStart Delegate"